# libGDX 3D texture is stretched

Tags: java, libgdx, 3d, textures, maze

I'm working on a 3D maze game using libGDX. I'm using MeshBuilder to render the walls. All walls are a single part made using a ModelBuilder in the create():

```
    ModelBuilder modelBuilder = new ModelBuilder();
    MeshPartBuilder meshBuilder;
    Vector3 corner00 = new Vector3(),
            corner10 = new Vector3(),
            corner11 = new Vector3(),
            corner01 = new Vector3(),
            normal = new Vector3();
    modelBuilder.begin();

    Texture wallTexture = new Texture("wall.PNG");
    wallTexture.setWrap(Texture.TextureWrap.Repeat, Texture.TextureWrap.Repeat);
    wallTexture.setFilter(Texture.TextureFilter.Linear, Texture.TextureFilter.Linear);
    Material material = new Material(new Material(TextureAttribute.createDiffuse(wallTexture)));
    meshBuilder = modelBuilder.part("room1", GL20.GL_TRIANGLES,
            VertexAttributes.Usage.Position | VertexAttributes.Usage.Normal |
                    VertexAttributes.Usage.TextureCoordinates, material);
    Array<Wall> walls = level.getWalls();
    for (Wall wall : walls) {
        Vertex v1 = wall.getV1();
        Vertex v2 = wall.getV2();
        meshBuilder.rect(corner00.set(v1.getX(), v1.getY(), 0), corner10.set(v2.getX(), v2.getY(), 0),
                corner11.set(v2.getX(), v2.getY(), 10), corner01.set(v1.getX(), v1.getY(), 10),
                normal.set(wall.getNormal(), 0));
    }
    Model worldModel = modelBuilder.end();
    instance = new ModelInstance(worldModel);
```

I do this in order to decrease the number of draw calls. But I came across a texture-mapping problem:
[image]
The wall texture is stretched. How can I make it repeat the texture instead of stretching?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After spending time learning more the libGDX 3D structure, I managed to fix it:

```
meshBuilder.setUVRange(0,0,Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/wallTexture.getWidth(),1)
```

While building the mesh part, I set the UV range from (0,0) to (n,1) - n is the number of times the texture image can fit inside the rect.